# declare javascript methods in Angular 2 / typescript to avoid propery x does not exist errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, declare, mixpanel

I use some JavaScript in my Angular 2, TypeScript project.
For example I use MixPanel that have a javascript file and some methods that look like this:

```
mixpanel.people.set({
    "$first_name": "Joe",
    "$last_name": "Doe",
    "$created": "2013-04-01T09:02:00",
    "$email": "joe.doe@example.com"
});
```

and this:

```
   mixpanel.track("Video played", {
        "Video length": 213,
        "id": "hY7gQr0"
    });
```

Calling this methods work, but typescript can not find any definitions of this mixpanel object so it throws errors. This is problematic because I can't compile with these errors...

Therefore, I am using this little hack to declare mixpanel like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var mixpanel: {
  track(event: string, data: any): void;
  identify(data: any): void;
  people(data: any): void;
  track_links(domQuery: string, eventName: string, properties: any): void;
};

@Injectable()
export class MixPanelService {

  constructor() { }

  public track(event: string, data: any) {
    mixpanel.track(event, data);
  }

  public track_links(domQuery: string, eventName: string, properties: any) {
    mixpanel.track_links(domQuery, eventName, properties);
  }

  public identify(id: string) {

    mixpanel.people.set({ <---- ERROR: Property 'set' does not exist on type '(data: any) => void'.at line 37 col 21
      '$first_name': id
    });
    mixpanel.identify(id);

  }
}
```

I am declaring **mixpanel.people**, but not **mixpanel.people.set**. 
This causes an error.

Anyone know how I should declare mixpanel var to fix this? Or if there is a better solution?

Comment: It might, I believe looking at the defs. Can you put the errors here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare var mixpanel:any;
```

can solve your all problems;

Answer (score 1):

Make an own class for MixPanel, like:

```
export class MixPanel
{
    track(event: string, data: any): void
    {
    }

    identify(data: any): void
    {
    }
    ...
}
```